# Performance implications of ||> and |||> pipeline operators in F#

Tags: performance, f#, functional-programming, inline, pipeline

This question basically expands on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649893/performance-implications-of-point-free-style) where the answer is that the single argument pipeline operator `|>` is compiled to the same CIL as the unpiped version. But what about `||>` and `|||>`? MSDN suggests that real tuples are used to wrap the arguments.

**But do `||>` and `|||>` really allocate a .NET Tuple to wrap the arguments and then unwrap them again** just pass them to a function or is the compiler optimized to handle these operators by just rewriting the CIL like it does with `|>`?

**Update:**

Thank you for the answers. It depends on whether the `--optimize+` parameter is passed to the F# compiler.

Default release builds in with F# 3.1 in Visual Studio 2013 don't create tuples. Default debug builds do create tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, where possible, the compiler will optimize away the operators just like it does with `|>`.

Just as a fun example, the compiler will optimize this code

```
let add a b = a + b
let test() = (1,2) ||> add
```

to this

```
3
```

And even if you parameterised `test`

```
let test t = t ||> add
```

it would compile to this C# equivalent

```
int test(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

In real, more complex code, you might not see such extreme optimizations but it gives you an idea of what the compiler can do.

Comment: Tarmil says it does not do that in his example. Might this be different for operators?

Comment: I don't see the same results as @Tarmil, that `f` function compiles to `x + y`. Perhaps there are differences in compiler version or how the code is compiled.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it. Which version of F# or Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: `Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 12.0.21005.1`

Comment: Thanks again! I had the same results with default release builds in with F# 3.1 in Visual Studio 2013. Default debug builds gave me Tarmil's results.

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT**: Originally I actually confused the optimized and non-optimized assemblies when trying out, and thought it didn't optimize it out; but it actually does.*

I actually tried it out. I tried the following module:

```
module Library1

let f x y = (x, y) ||> (+)
```

And then decompiling it with ILSpy.

When compiling without optimizations (`--optimize-`), it gives the following:

```
public static int f(int x, int y)
{
    Tuple<int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(x, y);
    int item = tuple.Item1;
    int item2 = tuple.Item2;
    return item + item2;
}
```

When compiling with optimizations (`--optimize+`), it gives the following:

```
public static int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

So yes, the optimizations do remove the tuple creation.

Comment: Thanks for actually trying it out. Have you tried piping into a function instead of an operator? It might make a difference since operators are inlined themselves.

Comment: That's the behavior with the `--optimize-` flag. Otherwise you'll get `public static int f(int x, int y) { return x + y; }`

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. So the `--optimize` flag actually does not optimize this code in this case? Which version of F# and/or Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @kaefer: You're right, somehow I did something wrong in my testing and I was looking at my non-optimized assembly when I thought it was the optimized one. My bad.

Comment: For extra fun, try `--localoptimize-`, which keeps the tuple but eliminates the temp vars. Going by the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx), it should have come as argument to the `--optimize[+|-]` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the F# operators are declared as `inline`, which means that they essentially work by text replacement before the optimizer even comes into play.  For reference, here is the definition of `||>` from the source code

```
let inline (||>) (x1,x2) f = f x1 x2
```

If you compare this to `|>` which is

```
let inline (|>) a b = b a
```

I would expect similar optimisations